# Как сделать доступ к рабочим столам разных пользователей на Windows 10?

Tags: windows, teamviewer

Есть только доступ к TeamViewer. Нужны множественные пользователи и доступ параллельно к их рабочим столам

Comment: тимвью подключает к активному рабочему столу - который всегда почему-то один.

Answer (score 2):

> Пользователи Microsoft Windows 10 Pro и Enterprise  редакций могут
>   удаленно подключаться к своим компьютерам через службу удаленных
>   рабочих столов (RDP). Однако есть ограничение на количество
>   одновременных RDP сессии – возможна одновременная работа только одного
>   удаленного пользователя. При попытке открыть вторую RDP сессию, сеанс
>   первого пользователя предлагается завершить.

Соответственно - стандартные средства Microsoft Windows 10 не позволяют Вам одновременной работы нескольких пользователей.

У приложения TeamViewer в бесплатной версии нет возможности одновременной работы нескольких пользователей, насколько мне известно.

> Количество одновременных сеансов TeamViewer к устройству зависит от
>   Вашей лицензии. Для каждого канала вашей лицензии, вы можете запустить
>   несколько одновременных сеансов TeamViewer с компьютера. Только один
>   канал может быть использован для каждого компьютера.

Вот ссылка на FAQ: [How many simultaneous TeamViewer sessions can I establish from my device](https://www.teamviewer.com/ru/help/443-How-many-simultaneous-TeamViewer-sessions-can-I-establish-from-my-device)

Оттуда видно следующее (Слева - License, справа - Maximum number of simultaneous sessions):

1. Business -   3
2. Premium  - 10
3. Corporate -  15

Однако, определенное время тому назад была такая тулза, о ней писали на [xakep.ru](https://xakep.ru/2013/10/31/remote-acess-tools/), как *TeamViewer Host*, прикрепил ссылку и даю основной текст:

> *TeamViewer Host* - запускается как системная служба и используется для круглосуточного доступа к удаленному компу, включая вход в систему
>   / выход из нее. Получается, что TeamViewer Host позволяет организовать
>   сервер терминалов, причем он поддерживает неограниченное число
>   клиентов для одного сервера (число клиентов ограничено только
>   вычислительными возможностями твоего компа). Также нужно отметить, что
>   для установки TeamViewer Host нужны права администратора, которые не
>   всегда есть, поэтому все равно в большинстве случаев будешь
>   пользоваться обычным TeamViewer. Однако если нужно настроить всего
>   один комп (или просто организовать к нему удаленный доступ, скажем из
>   дому), то TeamViewer Host не нужен. Ради справедливости нужно
>   отметить, что если на компьютере А запущен обычный TeamViewer (не
>   Host), то к нему могут подключиться компы Б, В, Г (число три приведено
>   для примера) для совместного администрирования. Другое дело, что нужно
>   согласовывать действия администраторов, поскольку клавиатура и мышь
>   общие, но один может настраивать, остальные будут наблюдать.

Да, а еще, тоже определенное время назад, была такая плюшка, как TeamViewer Server, вот только найти про нее мало чего удается.

Может быть Вас просто устроит конференция в TeamViewer? Не рассматривали данный вариант: [Конференции и взаимодействие](https://www.teamviewer.com/ru/use-cases/meetings-and-collaboration/)

Comment: Мне нестандартными значит средствами

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, я Вам написал по поводу `TeamViewer`- в бесплатной версии нельзя.